# Kubernetes Persistent Volume Claim FileSystemResizePending

Tags: kubernetes

i have a persistent volume claim for a kubernetes pod which shows the message "Waiting for user to (re-)start a pod to finish file system resize of volume on node." if i check it with 'kubectl describe pvc ...'

The rezising itself worked which was done with terraform in our deployments but this message still shows up here and i'm not really sure how to get this fixed? The pod was already restarted several times - i tried kubectl delete pod and scale it down with kubectl scale deployment.

Does anyone have an idea how to get rid of this message?[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7cgc.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you share the "output" from the image as text or codeblock? Then it is easier to read

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to consider:

1. Instead of using the Terraform, try resizing the PVC by editing it manually. After that wait for the underlying volume to be expanded by the storage provider and verify if the `FileSystemResizePending` condition is present by executing `kubectl get pvc <pvc_name> -o yaml`. Than, make sure that **all the associated pods are restarted** so the whole process can be completed. Once file system resizing is done, the PVC will automatically be updated to reflect new size.
2. Make sure that your volume type is supported for expansion. You can expand the following types of volumes:

- gcePersistentDisk
- awsElasticBlockStore
- Cinder
- glusterfs
- rbd
- Azure File
- Azure Disk
- Portworx
- FlexVolumes
- CSI

3. Check if in your `StorageClass` the `allowVolumeExpansion` field is set to `true`.